# TRIGGER and select issue

Tags: mysql, triggers

I don't understand why mysql ( 5.5 )  doesn't want set up my trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_apres_delete_filecache  AFTER DELETE ON oc_filecache FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
Declare id_parent VARCHAR;  
Select distinct(id) from oc_storages where numeric_id = OLD.parent into id_parent ; 
INSERT INTO histo_filecache (action, date_action, path,who)  VALUES ('delete', NOW (), OLD.path,id_parent); 
END//
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` is not a function. Try `select distinct id ...`:

```
Select distinct id from oc_storages where numeric_id = OLD.parent into id_parent ;
```

You also have to make sure, that the above query returns a single record only. Without any error message, this is the only thing I can see in your code at the moment.

UPDATE

You should also provide a length of the varchar variable:

```
Declare id_parent VARCHAR(x);
```

But I would also double check the data type, since ids are usually numeric values.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but i have this error : 

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
Select distinct id from oc_storages where numeric_id = OLD.parent into id_par' at line 4